# Refresh QPushButtons when QPushButton is pressed

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to refresh few QPushButton icons when I press one QPushButton, is there a way when I press one of four buttons, all the four get updated?

```
void VMesa::on_mano1_clicked()
{
    Tablero* tJuego = Tablero::getInstance();
    Deck* mazo = Deck::getInstance();

    tJuego->getJActual() == 1 ? tJuego->setJActual(2) : tJuego->setJActual(1);
}
```

When the window is loaded, it charges an Icon at four buttons like this code:

```
QPixmap pixmap = tJuego->getCartaQString(mazo->topCarta());
QIcon ButtonIcon = pixmap;
ui->campo5->setIcon(ButtonIcon);
ui->campo5->setIconSize(QSize(ui->campo5->width(), ui->campo5->height()));
```

I need that when I press each of the four buttons, all get updated with another image(from Carta<) from the Stack(Mazo). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to use [signals and slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) of Qt, more precisely the signal `clicked()` inherent to a `QPushButton`. If you have 4 QPushButton, I think you will have to connect each one to a different slot, and in this slot, update the other. It will look like this :

```
connect(m_pButton1, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onButton1clicked()));

...

void VMesa::onButton1clicked()
{
    //set icons for the other 3 buttons
}
```